# Lazy loading collection of objects for insert with HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, hibernate-mapping

I need to load a collection of objects from DB via HQL with the purpose of using those objects only for setting an association in some new records.

Consider the following: I need to send an email to all students with nr of credits > 50 and I need to keep a trace of all the recipients included in the transmission.

First select the students:

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Student student left join fetch student.scores where student.credits>50");
List<Student> students = query.list();
```

this will return a list of students with all columns (non association attributes like first name, last name, date of birth...) loaded for each record. 
The problem is that when I have a lot of data, the above query is very slow and occupies a lot of memory due to a large amount of useless data being transferred from db to app server.
I can't make all attributes lazy loaded directly in the entity as this will kill other areas of the application.

What I need is a way of loading the above collection with only the ids fetched as I am using the objects just to set them for some new objects in an association. I know this can be done for OneToMany associations easily but how can I do it for a direct queried collection?

```
List<Recipient> emailRecipients = new ArrayList<>();
for(Student student: students){
   Recipient rec = new Recipient();

   //this is the only usage of the student object
   rec.setStudent(student);
   ...
   set other properties for the recipient
   sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(rec);
}
```

Inside the recipient, the Student object is setup like this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "STD_ID", nullable = false)
private Student student;
```

As you can see, only the id of the Student object is needed, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one Hibernate specific trick, which allows you to set the FK association even if you don't provide an actual managed entity. Let's say we have a studentId, we can simply set:

```
Student student = new Student();
student.setId(studentId);
rec.setStudent(student);
```

This is not supported by standard JPA, but it works with Hibernate. Just make sure you don't have any cascade propagation from child to parent (which you should not have anyway).

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've loaded the studentId only and modified the mapping inside the recipient to include the studentId as well:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "STD_ID", insertable=false, updatable = false)
private Student student;

@Column(name = "STD_ID", nullable = false)
private Long studentId;
```

now I can simply set the studentId and the performance is much better.